# Extracting dates when writing csv from R to excel

Tags: r, excel, quantmod, yahoo-api

I am extracting a list of price of a stock (Open, High, Low, Close, Volume etc), from r (quantmod was used to bring in the data from external source) to excel, however the date column is omitted.

I thought the issue is in the fact that because the 'date' is not recognized as a variable, whereas other columns are (Open, High etc). I've tried to insert the dates via as.Date (from Sys.Date-365 to Sys.Date, as I only require a one year set of data), and cbind them. However because the length is different, and this is a vector based list, it won't fit (the data that comes from external source only shows in a working days, where as.Date will have full 365 days shown.

```
x <- getSymbols("SPY", src ="yahoo", from=Sys.Date()-365, to=Sys.Date(), auto.assign=FALSE )

write.csv(s, file = "test.csv")
```

Writing csv like above will result in the date column showing as 1, 2, 3, 4 ..., but i need the date that matches the price like it shows in the View mode in r.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has something to do with how the `xts zoo` object created by `getSymbols` stores its row indices. Just convert it to a normal `data.frame` on export to include the date indices as strings:

```r
ysyms <- getSymbols("SPY",
                    src = "yahoo",
                    from = Sys.Date()-365,
                    to = Sys.Date(),
                    auto.assign = FALSE
                    )

# Convert to data.frame on export.
write.csv(as.data.frame(ysyms), file = "test.csv")
```

Comment: LEGEND. all sorted thanx

Answer (score 1):

The `x` in the question is not a data.frame -- it is zoo/xts object, so use `write.zoo`:

```
write.zoo(x, "file.csv", sep = ",")
```